# How can I do something x number of times in Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This seems like a basic problem but I haven't been able to find a simple solution so far.

In my HBS template I would like to do something 'x' number of times. I was hoping there might be some sort of #times block helper but it would appear not.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: have you looked at each helper ?http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each

Comment: Yup! Rather than feeding the block helper an array I'd like to simply feed it a number though

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't a helper I'm aware of existing, you could create a component that gives you the functionality you want.

https://ember-twiddle.com/d21713e3746e36643196

Comment: I ended up needing this a couple times since answering this and created an addon for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-x-times